# Which Terminal theme and plugin is this

Tags: macos, terminal, plugins, themes

I came across the following screenshot of someone's Terminal and I'd like to know how that person managed to display the full path on top. I also like the color scheme.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: Terminal window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is on the agnoster zsh theme with a custom color scheme.

[RobbyRussell Angoster theme for zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#agnoster)

You may need to install Oh-My-Zsh first. For that, take a look at [ohmyzsh](http://ohmyz.sh)

Comment: Almost all the git visual customizations of titlebar and prompt line are based on `zsh` so that would be a great place to start in making your path look like the one pictured and have better control over what's in the title bar of the terminal.app window.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some parameters using the Terminal Preferences.

The rest is up to the application that's running. It this case that's might be an editor, or a specific https://spaceship.airforce/ related application.